# Name the primary key of Container in Cosmbos DB Sql Api different than "id"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working on Azure and I have created a database with Cosmos DB SQL API. After creating a container I see that the primary key is always named "id". Is there any way to create a container with PK with name different than "id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PK = primary key, by the way ;) It's the "main" key for the record, it is not private :)

And no, as far as I know you cannot change the primary key name. It is always "id". Specifically it must be in lowercase, "Id" is not accepted.

Comment: BTW, pk in cosmos = partition key not primary key

Answer (score 4):

Every document has a unique id called `id`. This cannot be altered. If you don't set a value, it is assigned a GUID.

When using methods such as `ReadDocument()` (or equivalent, based on the SDK) for direct reads instead of queries, a document's `id` property must be specified.

Now, as far as *partitioning* goes, you can choose any property you want to use as the partition key.

And if you have additional domain-specific identifiers (maybe a part number), you can always store those in their own properties as well. In this example though, just remember that, while you can *query* for documents containing a specific part number, you can only do a direct-read via `id`. If direct reads will be the majority of your read operations, then it's worth considering the use of `id` to store such a value.